# Return async operation result to the original thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Can the result of an [async operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) be returned to the thread that initiated it (ie.`AsyncCallback` invoked in the original thread)?

Here's an example

```
    void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Func<bool> action = () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ": Running");
            return true;
        };

        AsyncCallback onComplete = (r) =>
        {
            bool result = action.EndInvoke(r);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ": Completed");
        };

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ": Main");
        IAsyncResult iar = action.BeginInvoke(onComplete, null);
    }
```

Its output is something like:

```
5: Main
6: Running
6: Completed
```

What I'd like to achieve is the `onComplete` callback executing in the main thread (eg. Completed and Main will have the same thread id printed in this example)

(I know this can be achieved with a `BackgroundWorker` ie. it's `RunWorkerCompleted` event is fired in the original thread and therefore the return value of the function invoked in the background thread can be returned to the original thread)

Comment: So why not just use BackgroundWorker? It isn't sealed so you can even derive from it to add your own magic.

Comment: Conversly you can probably send a reference to the main thread along with your task and cross thread access it. But to test that and making sure that it always works? Brrr...

Comment: @Nebula access to a `Thread` doesn't allow you to push *work* to a thread; for that, you need some kind of work queue mechanism.

Comment: @MarcGravell Right, thanks. I'd never attempt on making something like that anyway though =p

Answer (score 5):

This is largely a question for the `SynchronizationContext` and `TaskScheduler` implementations that you choose to use. In the case of many UI frameworks (winforms, WPF, etc), then yes: if you start work on the UI thread, the callback can happen on the UI thread - but this does not apply in the general case, where a `ThreadPool` thread is more likely to win. Ultimately, you can't simply force work back to a particular thread, *unless* that thread is *by design* checking some queue of work, and dequeing / executing packets of work as they arrive (which is exactly what UI frameworks do).

Comment: So: just use whatever thread type fits your bill? Or is that too crude?

Comment: Assuming this is for a WPF application guess could I do something like `action.BeginInvoke((r) =>Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(onComplete(r)), null)` ie. when the action completes on the secondary thread it'll queue the `onComplete` callback on the UI thread? But was wondering if there's some other way it could be done (without  the explicit Dispatcher call) - something like setting `SynchronizingObject` to not null in a `Timer`.

Comment: @ubi if you're starting from the UI thread, it should already work fine